# How to write input value with razor in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I use resources file in MVC3 project for multilanguages.

```
[Display(Name = "Search", ResourceType = typeof(LanguageResources.Lang))]
public string Search { get; set; }
```

I cant write an input value with razor.

`@Html.LabelFor(o => o.Search)` is works on page but i need to write value of inputs.

```
<input class="searchInput" type="text" name="name" value='@Html.ValueFor(o => o.Search)' />
```

i tried this but value is empty in html page source.

Comment: Please elabroate **need to write value of inputs**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Razor syntax you can write your code like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Search)
```

If you want to fill the value in your textbox during your get method, you just need to assign the value to your `Search` property and pass the model to your view and that is that. See the code below:

```
model.Search = "Hello World";
return View(model);
```

Now you will be able to see that text "Hello World" is assign to your textbox when the page get load.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<input class="searchInput" type="text" name="name" value='@Model.Search' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

before `return View(yourmodel);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

in .aspx view file

```
<%:Html.TextboxFor(o=>o.Search)%>
```

in razor view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.Search)
```

In razor it can also be like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(o => o.Search)
```

Comment: in razor it might be like  `@Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.Search)`